# Selecting between cpuidle governors - Ubuntu 16.04 running 4.4.0-59 kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, intel-core-i7

I am trying to find out how to select between the cpuidle governors *menu* and *ladder*. Currently my system is configured with *menu* but I want to switch it to *ladder*.

So far I know that it should be possible through *cpuidle sysfs* (according to https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cpuidle/sysfs.txt) but I don't know how to set the *cpuidle_sysfs_switch* boot option, or what that really means.

Comment: adding boot parameters: http://askubuntu.com/a/19487 ... https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters

Comment: @quixotic Thank you! This is exactly what I needed and it worked.

Now I have in _/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuidle/_ these files: `available_governors`, `current_governor` and `current_driver`. The governor can be changed by writing either one from `available_governors` into `current_governors`